# Extensive book on random walks

Tags: reference-request, random-walk

I am looking for an extensive book on (/that includes) random walks. Preferably, a bit more modern than Feller (1971). It should give a rather holistic view, i.e. graduate level. I have seen this thread [What is a good/extensive undergraduate level reference on random walks?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496070/what-is-a-good-extensive-undergraduate-level-reference-on-random-walks)

Any other recommendations? Preferably, not online lecture notes but a published book, one could properly reference when writing a text.

Comment: Lawler and Limic's book is pretty extensive.  Is there something specific you were looking for that isn't in there?

Comment: Yeah, renewal theory for instance. They did not cover it, I believe, even though it's closely related.